# GraphQL-java with Spring boot query request inside query

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql-java

I have a schema like below.

```
type Board {
    id: ID,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    replies: [Replies]
}

type Replies {
    id: ID,
    content: String
}
```

Then, while searching for the board, there are replies related to the board.

Here you can get the board and replies by querying like this:

```
query{
    getBoard(id: "xxx") {
        id,
        title,
        content: String,
        replies {
            id,
            content
        }
    }
}
```

but what i want
How to implement in backend java without using directive to get the last 5 replies when retrieving the selected board and replies inside?

I'm developing via https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart.

```
query{
    getBoard(id: " xxx") {
        id,
        title,
        content: String,
        replies(limit: 5) {
            id,
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a new data fetcher (.type()) when you are creating your graphql.schema.idl.RuntimeWiring function. So you can add your new graphql.schema.DataFetcher function to recover what you want.

Comment: thank you for the reply.
Do you have any sample code or guide documents?